# Is the number 3514524017891864227 an error?

Tags: python

I just started coding, so I don't know if this is normal or not... but I was experimenting on Python 3.7 shell. Anyways, I typed in:

```
name = "Martin"
print(name)
```

and as a result I got the number 3514524017891864227. I don't know if this is some sort of error or something and I'm hoping that someone could explain this to me.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Interesting.  If you start up a new shell, and enter just those two lines, do you get the same result?

Comment: This is very unusual. What happens if you try `dir()`?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it. Is it a fresh shell or did anything happen before it? If so please show us the "before" part too.

Comment: Can you show your full shell session?  This shouldn't happen

Comment: this is the full shell session...

Comment: And I keep trying and continue getting this result.

Comment: have you defined any function as `print(..)`?

Comment: Can you start the screenshot at the version information downwards?  I can only reproduce something like this by doing something silly like `print = id`

Comment: Yes....I have defined it

Comment: @AnthonySottile Or `print = lambda x: hash(x)`

Comment: I'm sorry Antony Sottile, I don't think I understand...

Comment: @DeepSpace golfed: `print = hash` -- this also seems more likely

Comment: @Margi he wants a screenshot like [this](https://i.imgur.com/5vQ1DUm.png)

Comment: @Margi He meant you could reproduce something similar by doing that. And what do you mean you "have defined it"? Show it!

Comment: This question went from _interesting_ to a beginner mistake. :P . Although, a good learning chance.

Comment: @AnthonySottile I get the same number

Comment: @MaJoR it isn't solved. I feel some important info is not being provided though, I just don't know what it is

Comment: @Margi, just open a new Python shell, and post a screenshot of the whole window.

Comment: @Margi, the point is that you _shouldn't_ be assigning anything to `print`. It's a built-in function that you can use automatically. When you assign something to it (like `id` or `hash`) you change its behaviour. In that case the `id()` or `hash()` function will run when you call `print()`.

Comment: @MaJoR The problem is that when I open a new one, it works, but now matter how often I try on the old one, it doesn't.

Comment: @Margi, that's because `print` has been redefined on the old one. Try `print = __builtins__.print`, then `print(name)` again.

Comment: How do I even attach a screenshot?

Comment: @Chris Thanks! It worked!

Comment: You included a screenshot in your original question. You can [edit] it and replace the old one or add another.

Comment: Now, since Chris has told you, what you had done (mistakenly). I would recommend you to post an answer to this question yourself, and get that Reputation. :D

Answer (score 2):

Somehow `print` has been redefined, possibly via

```
print = id
```

or similar. This points `print` to the same function that `id` points to. In this case, when you run

```
print(name)
```

you get the same behaviour that

```
id(name)
```

would give you. Normally assigning anything to a built-in function like `print` is a mistake.

The original `print` function should still be available in `__builtins__`, so you can redefine `print` back to its original behaviour with

```
print = __builtins__.print
```

`print(name)` should now work as expected.